# How to separate html from js file and display content?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a code as follow:

```
var info = {
    "Company": "ABC",
    "Team": "JsonNode",
    "Number": 4,
    "Time": "1 day"
};

var layout = "<ol><li>Info: </li><ol><ul>Company:       {{info.Company}}</ul><ul>Team: {{info.Team}}</ul></ol><li>Number: {{info.Number}}</li><li>Time: {{info.Time}}</li><ol>";

function generatePdf(layout,info) 
{
    var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');
    console.log('generating pdf');
    wkhtmltopdf(layout, {
       //console.log('debug');
       output: './file.pdf',
       "viewport-size": "1280x1024",
       "page-width": "400",
       "page-height": "600"
    });
}
generatePdf(layout,info);
```

And now I can generate a pdf file but pdf file's content is not right. is is:

```
    1. Info:
    Company: {{info.Company}}

    Team: {{info.Team}}
    2. Number: {{info.Number}}
    3. Time: {{info.Time}}
```

My problems here are:

1: How to separate html template(var layout) to  a file.

2: info.Company must be ABC, info.Number must be 4

Please give me a help!

Comment: Your template HTML is incorrect to begin with, you almost randomly open and close `ul` and `ol` elements and some data isn't even inside an `li` (that stands for list item if that gives you an indication of whats going on) - Also, how does company info with a submenu count every thing in the submenu as if its in the main menu (aka how can `number` be 4 when its the second in the primary list?)

Comment: can you please post a fiddle

Comment: @KarthickKumar or, if possible, your code in a SO snippet (its the document icon with the `<>` in it)

Comment: give this code some php tidy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution from my friend: code as follow , and it work for my case.
He used swig , a template engine:

```
// get json object from json file
var info = require('./data.json');

var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');
var swig  = require('swig');
// Compile a file and store it, rendering it later
var tpl = swig.compileFile('public/template.html');

var layout = tpl({ info: info});

function generatePdf(layout,info) {
    wkhtmltopdf(layout, {output: './file.pdf'});
  }
exports.create_pdf_file = function() {
    generatePdf(layout,info);
}
```

I post answer. maybe someone need it

Answer (score 1):

please rearrange your layout variable like this and check

```
var layout = "<ol><li>Info: </li><ol><ul>Company:"+info.Company+"</ul><ul>Team: "+info.Team+"</ul></ol><li>Number:"+info.Number+"</li><li>Time:"+info.Time+"</li><ol>";
```

Comment: Could you please help with the first question? The second one is done!

Answer (score 1):

If your javascript runs in Node.js you can use

```
var layout = require("./layout.json");
```

to get your layout from a file. I think on your webapp you use angular to replace `{{var}}` with its content, but if you generate a PDF there is no angular to write the values, meaning you have to do it in JS like this

```
layout.replace("{{info.Company}}",info.Company);
```

Comment: When I require .html file. an error occured. logs:(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <ol><li>Info: </
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Quick fix: change `layout.html` to `layout.json` and put `"<ol><li>Info: </li><ol><ul>Company:       {{info.Company}}</ul><ul>Team: {{info.Team}}</ul></ol><li>Number: {{info.Number}}</li><li>Time: {{info.Time}}</li><ol>"` inside the layout.json

Comment: Thanks! But If layout file very large (1000 lines). I think your solution will have some problems. Do you have another way?